# how to handle timeout error and make sure to execute request just once

Tags: system-design

I have been asked below question at one of the rounds:

If there is a service(API-1) calling another service API-2(which interacts with DB and updates the data).
e.g. If API-1 passes $500 as the request to API-2 for some deduction in the DB amount(consider cashapp or paypal usecases), and API-2 fails for some reason.(could be network error, timeout error or anything). How do we make sure that the request should execute only once and deduction happens once?  and who should handle this? API-1 or API-2? How do we handle that?

Answer (score 0):

It should be handled by both in the sense, API-2 need to make sure that the request is idempotent and API-1 should provide the idempotency token so that API-2 failure of any sort can be recovered.